# $S=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb R^3|x_1 \geqslant 0, x_2 \geqslant 0, x_3\geqslant 0, x_1+x_2+x_3 \leqslant 1\}$, why does $\int_S 1$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$S=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb R^3|x_1 \geqslant 0, x_2 \geqslant 0, x_3\geqslant 0, x_1+x_2+x_3 \leqslant 1\}$, why does $\int_S 1$ exist?

Lemma: If $f:K \to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous, where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^m$, then $graph(f)$ has measure 0.
How does the lemma apply here?

Comment: what measure are you using for integration?

Comment: $S$ has measure different from zero and the integral represents the volume of $S.$ isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $ f: U \subset R^3 \to R $ is integrable if and only if the set of its points of discontinuity has zero measure. Note that in your case, where f = 1 and $ U = S $, these points are the boundary of $ S $ that is the graph of the function $ g (x, y) = \sqrt {1- x ^ 2 + y ^ 2}, \forall x,y \geq 0 $.

Comment: I don't think it is the case to summon such a strong result. Here one is simply integrating a constant over a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. It is important that the set be *measurable* and of *finite measure*. Moreover, the parametrization you gave of $S$ is wrong, the right one being $z=1-x-y$.

Comment: Yes, you  are right, I'm wrong with parametrization. The right parametrization is $z= \sqrt{1- x^2 -y^2}$. But, he want use the lema and o lema use a notion of  set with measure zero.